# Random number to store inside array list and choose from it

Tags: java, arrays, random, arraylist

I am trying to create a program to generate random number and store into `arraylist`.
Meanwhile getting the number stored to do `multiply`.

I have store the generated number but how do I actually get the number that I wanted.
For this example, i trying to get the `3rd number`, which step did i missed out?

```
public class arraylist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        int numtogen;
        int third;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many number do you want to generate: ");
        numtogen = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What number do you want to multiply with the third number: ");
        third = scan.nextInt();

        HashSet<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();

        // Prevent repeat
        for (int x = 1; x <= numtogen; ++x) {
            while (true) {
                // generate a range from 0-100
                int ranNum = rand.nextInt(100);

                if (generated.contains(ranNum)) {

                    continue;
                } else {
                    list.add(ranNum);
                    System.out.println("Number " + x + "=" + " = " + ranNum);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        int numinlist;
        while (!list.isEmpty()) {

            // Integer[] numlist= numbinlist.hasNextInt;

            // int answer = numlist[2]*third;
            // System.out.println("Answer to first number  = "+answer);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is rather unclear.

Comment: The 3rd random number is just a random number.  The List or Set is redundant so you can just do `int triple = rand.nextInt(100) * 3;` regardless of what they enter (I assume this is just an exercise ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the generation of non-repeating numbers to:

```
Set<Integer> generated = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
// Prevent repeat
while (generated.size() < numtogen) {
    generated.add(rand.nextInt(100));
}
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(generated);
```

I'll edit this answer as soon as I understand your actual problem and know the answer.

Comment: Well optimized code ! . newbieprogrammer you do not need to use infinite while loop and break it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the 3rd generated number try this:

```
int number = list.get(2);
```

Comment: the third number would actually be `list.get(2);`

Comment: +1  seems like a good guess.  The question needs editing anyway. Oh, fix the index, please

Comment: oh..list.get to retrieve the number..thanks thanks that is what I looking for.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= numtogen; ++x) {
    while (true) {
        // generate a range from 0-100
        int ranNum = rand.nextInt(100);

        if (generated.contains(ranNum)) {

            continue;
        } else {
            list.add(ranNum);
            System.out.println("Number " + x + "=" + " = " + ranNum);
            break;
        }
     }
 }
```

to:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= numtogen; ++x) {
    // generate a range from 0-100
    int ranNum = rand.nextInt(100);
    if (generated.contains(ranNum)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        list.add(ranNum);
        System.out.println("Number " + x + "=" + " = " + ranNum);
    }
}
```

Then, all you need to do to access the 3rd number is something like:

```
int answer = (list.get(2) * third);
```